# Sort the json in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I want to sort the Array, according to the property such as this:

```
[
{num:5},{num:3},{num:6},{num:9}
]
```

After the sort, I want to get

```
[
{num:3},{num:5},{num:6},{num:9}
]
```

How to do it in JavaScript?

Comment: What did you try already? there are a tons of questions like this one anyway! :P

Comment: @briosheje I do not do kind of the sort before. I have no idea. :(

Comment: You can either use .sort, .filter or .map, your choice! :P

Comment: Do you have a JSON string with that content? Otherwise it's just an array of objects, and there is no JSON involved at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A sort function (literal) returns 1, -1, 0 for ascending, descending and equal respectively.

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.num - b.num
});
```

Answer (score 6):

`the_array.sort(function(a,b) { return a.num-b.num } );`

where the function inside the sort() is the comparator

Answer (score 3):

```js
var arr = [
    {num:5},{num:3},{num:6},{num:9}
];

arr.sort(function(a,b) { return a.num-b.num; });

document.write(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

If you would need to sort items backwards it would be `b.num-a.num`.

Comment: I changed `console.log` to `document.write` and also added `JSON.stringify()` so as to make your snippet more useful :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you should learn to use lambda expression witch is the key of functional programming. The answer is quite easy:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){
     return a.num - b.num;
})
```

If you don't know the high order function or lambda you are not actually writing JavaScript code.

Comment: @nicael Actually, there are no answers while I'm editing this post.

Comment: There are *three answers* which were posted before yours and the are *completely identical*. Yours is, believe me, excess.

Comment: I think the answers should be based on their correctness rather than whether they are identical to others.

Comment: @nicael In this question, you should not only focus on the answer, as you know it's quite simple but what a JavaScript programmer should know is the  theory behind the answer, that's why I mention the two points in my answer and actually not excess.